# Python While loop with Organization growth not giving proper output

Tags: python, while-loop

I'm trying to write a program that calculates the population of growing organisms over a certain period of time:

> A local biologist needs a program to predict population growth. The inputs would be:
>
> - The initial number of organisms
> - The rate of growth (a real number greater than 1)
> - The number of hours it takes to achieve this rate
> - A number of hours during which the population grows
>
> For example, one might start with a population of 500 organisms, a growth rate of 2, and a growth period to achieve this rate of 6 hours. Assuming that none of the organisms die, this would imply that this population would double in size every 6 hours. Thus, after allowing 6 hours for growth, we would have 1000 organisms, and after 12 hours, we would have 2000 organisms.
>
> Write a program that takes these inputs and displays a prediction of the total population.

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#Currently trying with 10, 2, 2, 6, giving a total pop of 10

organisms = int(input("Enter the initial number of organisms:"))
rateOfGrowth = int(input("Enter the rate of growth [a real number > 0]: "))
numOfHours = int(input("Enter the number of hours to achieve the rate of growth: "))
totalHours = int(input("Enter the total hours of growth: "))

totalOrganisms = organisms
while numOfHours >= totalHours:
    organisms *= rateOfGrowth
    totalOrganisms += organisms
    numOfHours += numOfHours
print("The total population is ",totalOrganisms)
```

I've run through the logic a few times and can't figure out why I can't get the **desired answer** of 80

Comment: `while numOfHours >= totalHours:` doesn't look right. Don't you mean `<=`? (not gone through the rest of the code yet)

Comment: You can't have newlines in strings unless you use triple quotes. Why have you split the input prompts over 2 lines?

Comment: @Barmar that's only because my code editor push the lines over to that side because they were too long.

Comment: The Stack Overflow editor doesn't do that. But anyway, correcting the multi-line code and swapping `>=` (which is immediately True) to `<=` gets you to `70`

Comment: oh @roganjosh that did help. I'm not at 70 pop but don't know why it wont give me 80

Comment: Because you're missing off adding the starting culture of 10. You're calculating the growth in each period, but not adding on what you started with.

Comment: `numOfHours += numOfHours` doesn't seem right.

Comment: You need a separate variable for the number of hours that the simulation has been running, `numOfHours` is already used for the time it takes to achieve `rateOfGrowth`.

Comment: @Barmar isnt that the same as doing count += 1? But instead i used numOfHours += numOfHours so that it would eventually get to 6 and the loop would end

Comment: @Barmar so what would that look like?

Comment: `numOfHours += numOfHours` is the same as `numOfHours *= 2`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a loop, this can be calculated with a simple formula for exponential growth:

```
totalOrganisms = math.floor(organisms * rateOfGrowth ** (totalHours / numOfHours))
```

I use `math.floor()` because the formula can produce fractions if `totalHours` is not a multiple of `numOfHours`, but you can't have half an organism.

If you really have to use a loop, you have two problems.

First, your looping condition is backwards, it should use use `<=` rather than `>=`.

Second, `numOfHours += numOfHours` is doubling that variable each time. You need to use a separate variable for the time that the simulation has been running.

Third, you don't need to multiply `organisms` and also add it to `totalOrganisms`. Just multiply `organisms` by the growth rate, that will be the new total number of organisms.

```
hoursSoFar = 0
while hoursSoFar <= totalHours:
    organisms *= rateOfGrowth
    hoursSoFar += numOfHours
print("The total population is", organisms)
```

But if `totalHours` is not a multiple of `numOfHours`, this will ignore growth during the last partial period.

The equivalent formula that ignores the partial period would use integer division:

```
totalOrganisms = organisms * rateOfGrowth ** (totalHours // numOfHours)
```

Comment: That works for most numbers but this test case for example that doesn't work:Enter the initial number of organisms: 100
Enter the rate of growth [a real number > 0]: 5
Enter the number of hours to achieve the rate of growth: 2
Enter the total hours of growth: 25
The total population is  54591503356

Comment: What should the answer be instead?

Comment: 24414062500 is what the answer is supposed to be. idk why but your equation works with my other three problem checks beside this one

Comment: That's the correct answer for total hours = 24, not 25. You're ignoring the growth during the last hour.

Comment: You're assuming that growth happens instantaneously every 2 hours, all the organisms simultaneously split into 5.

Comment: Oh, you're right. Maybe that is a type in my homework. Thank you for your help though!

Comment: Maybe they also made that simplifying assumption. I've added a formula for that.

Comment: Oh yes! That did it!

Comment: Population growth isn't really a continuous process. What you really need to know is how often each organism gives birth to children, and how many children it has. This is actually a Fibonacci sequence.

Answer (score 0):

```
organisms = int(input("Enter the initial number of organisms:"))
rateOfGrowth = int(input("Enter the rate of growth : "))
numOfhours = int(input("Enter the number of hours to achieve the rate of growth: "))
totalhours = int(input("Enter the total hours of growth: "))
hours=0
while (hours <= totalhours):
    organisms*=rateOfGrowth
    hours += numOfhours
    if (hours==totalhours):
        break
print("The total population:" ,organisms)
```

Comment: It would great if you can add some explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```py
number = int(input("Enter the initial number of organisms: "))
rate = float(input("Enter the rate of growth [a real number > 1]: "))
cycleHours = int(input("Enter the number of hours to achieve the rate of growth:"))
totalHours = int(input("Enter the total hours of growth: "))
cycles = totalHours // cycleHours
for eachPass in range(cycles):
    number = number * rate
    print("The total population is", int(number))
```